# Mouseup event is not propagated to a popup window in IE 11

Tags: drag-and-drop, popup, internet-explorer-11

I've a legacy app that features a DND from a popup window to the main one.

It works fine in IE 8 but not in any of the newer versions of IE. The effect results in the drag ghost image being stuck in the source window and not going away after the drop had occurred.

Some debugging did in fact confirm that the 'mouseup' event does not get propagated back to the source window. What can be done to fix it? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

ITs a bit hard to begin to answer your question without some code....

use the File>Properties menu to find out which IE security zones the two windows(domains) map too...IE uses a different security model to other browsers... drag/drop is probably not allowed between local web files (using file: protocol) and internet or intranet sites.

Have you used the Dev tool yet to debug it? If you are using showModalDialog (which normally disables context menus) you can right click on a link (a) or input element to display the context menu so you can display the debugger for showModal content page.

If possible include a link to your website or a mashup (jsfiddle) with your questions.

Comment: can you back this up please `drag/drop is probably not allowed between local web files `, I'm not questioning it I think it's true. But I need an official resource on this matter please